# Android Rs232 Communication

Tags: android, serial-port

I am new in USB communication in Android and I want to communicate my android phone with an rs232 device. Firstly , i have an OTG cable an and USB to RS232 converter (model : Digitus USB to serial adaptor).

Now, i try to communicate my computer and my android phone using these cables. My first question is, Is that way correct or should i use another thing such as ardunio between android phone with my computer?

In my code , i defined my android phone an usb host and i send data from my computer's rs232 port but i never get any data in android phone. In this sutiation ,should my android phone be an usb host device like i do?

Note : My android phone is Samsung Note 2.

I know, My english is not good sorry for this.If you don't understood the problem i can write detail.

Comment: did you have succes with this so far? which USB-RS232 converter did you use to make it work?

Comment: No , i didn't. I changed the rs232 device with a device which has a usb port. Then They are communicated via USB port.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply! ... My device only has an RS232 port so I am stuck with that .... I am still a beginner in Android, so just exploring the possibilities at the moment ...

Answer (score 0):

You want to connect your Note 2 with your computer? So why dont you do this with adb?
Add internet-permission to your app, activate port forwarding on your pc and create a tcp socket.

[adb commands](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)

Comment: Actually, I want to communicate an android device with an rs232 device. Computer was my practice board. Thank you for answer, I find to solution for this question. Problem is my usb to serial adaptor. I should change.